# How to compare parts of lines of two txt files?

Tags: bash

I am given two txt files, each one of them with information aligned in several columns separated by a tab. What I want to do is look for lines in both files, where one of these columns match. --Not the whole lines, but only their first column parts should be identical. How do I do that in a bash script?

I have tried using `grep -Fwf`.

So this is what the files look like

```
aaaa   bbbb
cccc   dddd
```

and

```
aaaa   eeee
ffff   gggg
```

The output I'd like to get is something like:

```
bbbb and eeee match
```

I really haven't found a command that does both line-wise and by words comparison at the same time. 
Sorry for not providing any code of my own, I'm new to programming and couldn't come up with anything reasonable so far. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the join command? This in combination with sort maybe what you are looking for. https://shapeshed.com/unix-join/

for example:

```
$ cat a
aaaa   bbbb
cccc   dddd
$ cat b
aaaa   eeee
ffff   gggg
$ join a b
aaaa bbbb eeee
```

If the values in the first column are not sorted, than you have to sort them first, otherwise join will not work.

`join <(sort a) <(sort b)`

Kind regards 
Oliver

Answer (score 1):

There are different kinds and different tools to compare:

- diff
- cmp
- comm
- ...

All commands have options to vary the comparison.

For each command, you can specify filters. E.g.

```
# remove comments before comparison
diff <( grep -v ^# file1) <( grep -v ^# file2)
```

Without concrete examples, it is impossible to be more exact.

Comment: If it's impossible to write an exact answer, you should just not answer.

Comment: Why not lead to the right way and tell options? Now he is able to search for the commands and try it by himself -- the best way to learn!

Comment: You can only point someone into the right direction if you know the problem. Otherwise you point them somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your tab separated file maintains the correct file structure, this should work:

```
diff <(awk '{print $2}' f1) <(awk '{print $2}' f2) 
# File names: f1, f2
# Column: 2nd column.
```

The output when there is something different,

```
2c2
< dx
---
> ldx
```

No output when the column is the same.

I tried @Wiimm's answer and it didn't work for me.

Comment: `comm -12 ...` prints only identical lines.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `awk`, like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;b[NR]=$2;next}
     a[FNR]==$1{printf "%s and %s match\n", b[FNR], $2}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
bbbb and eeee match
```

Explanation (the same code broken into multiple lines):

```
# As long as we are reading file1, the overall record
# number NR is the same as the record number in the
# current input file FNR
NR==FNR{
    # Store column 1 and 2 in arrays called a and b
    # indexed by the record number
    a[NR]=$1
    b[NR]=$2
    next # Do not process more actions for file1
}

# The following code gets only executed when we read
# file2 because of the above _next_ statement

# Check if column 1 in file1 is the same as in file2
# for this line
a[FNR]==$1{
    printf "%s and %s match\n", b[FNR], $2
}
```